# Do "if conditions" affect the performance of kernel execution in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I am running a filter on an image and I perform a vertical pass followed by a horizontal pass. The function for this task is same for both the passes, only the argument values change. I'm calling the function in a loop. For vectorizing the operations in that function I have to write separate function calls for the two passes. The loop is now separate for horizontal and vertical passes. An "if condition" is now added because of this change and I noticed that even though the computations are vectorized, the kernel is taking longer to execute. I have run the code several times and the average time taken with the vectorized code is more than the original code. Is it because of the "if condition" plugged in the code?

Original code

```
global int* a;

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    filter(a + i, b, c);
}
```

Modified code

```
global int* a;

if(offset == 1)
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    filter_vertical(a + i, b, c);
}
else
    filter_horizontal(a, b, c);
```

Comment: Please, show us your sample code fragment. The way how you use `if` statement may change the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean `offset == 1` ?

```
if(offset = 1)
```

assigns 1 to offset which is an "extra latency" per thread. This is slower than original. But apart from that, "if" changes performance up or down depending on the pattern of a branch "taken" or  "not taken" grouped together because some architectures like GPU SIMD, fills bubbles to parallel SIMD pipelines when those are not same branch option with a neighbor pipeline so they are left to other wavefront threads' occupation opportunities, if they can't fill neiter, it will have less performance.

For more performance,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    filter_vertical(a + i, b, c);
}
```

to

```
    filter_vertical(a , b, c);
    filter_vertical(a + 1, b, c);
    filter_vertical(a + 2, b, c);
    filter_vertical(a + 3, b, c);
```

needs more instruction cache but, needs less branches, needs less memory usage and less cycles.

If you can group offset == 1 cases together, it would be faster if memory access operations doesn't affect it.